# Unable to invoke method in .asmx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have create below asmx file :

```
namespace Webhook
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class WebhookEvent : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void ReceiveEvents()
        {
            string fileName = @"D:\myfile.txt";

            try
            {
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{property: value}");

                // Check if file already exists. If yes, delete it.     
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(fileName);
                }

                // Create a new file     
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
                {
                    // Add some text to file    
                    Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("New Text File \n");
                    fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
                    /// byte[] author = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(jsonString);
                    // fs.Write(author, 0, author.Length);
                }

                // Open the stream and read it back.    
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
            }
        }


    }
}
```

In this file i am writing simple text in text file and sore in d drive.

Now Another application send data(via hook) on this file (http://myip/Webhook/WebhookEvent.asmx/ReceiveEvents) with following details :

```
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: weebdly
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-weebdly-Hook-Id: 123456

Body :
{
  "todayoff":"invitee"
}
```

So when ever another application send data on my application it is not calling this method.

I have also enable debug mode in IIS. So i can check the breaking point but it is not invoke this method.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you adding the following to your web.config file?

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

For enabling remote web service test page, just add HttpPost/HttpGet protocol in the webServices section of your web.config. By default, this option is disabled to increase the security in live environment, but you can enable it in web.config as follows for debugging the deployed web services.

Comment: are you getting a 404 response?

Comment: No. I can not check the responses as other application is not in my control

Comment: Are you able to invoke the method locally?

Comment: Yes i can invoke on locally.

Comment: Solved. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :
I have to just add " [ScriptService]"

So it is like :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
```

With ScriptService i am able to get data .